# Faking out FormData append with Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, form-data

I need to test a unit of code that constructs a FormData object, appends a file and submits an AJAX request to the server. The issue is that I don't actually have a file object to provide to the FormData `append` method call. So I wanted to spyOn the `append` method and call a fake function of my own. Is this possible? If not, how can I test my code.

The following is the unit of code I want to test:

```
var fd = new FormData();

// listOfFiles is an array of files and filename is a string
var file = _.findWhere(listOfFiles, { name: filename });

fd.append("file", file, filename);

$.ajax(/* options */);
```

The following is what I have for my unit test, which doesn't do the job:

```
it("does something", function() {
    var mockFiles = [{
        name: "Test File.pdf"
    }];

    // the addDocs call adds the files to the listOfFiles array above
    someView.addDocs(mockFiles);

    var ajaxSpy = spyOn($, "ajax");

    // THIS DOESN'T WORK
    spyOn(FormData.prototype, "append").andReturn(false);

    // this event causes the above unit of code to run
    app.trigger('someEvent');

    // do more stuff...
});
```

Right now I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': No function was found that matched the signature provided
```

Which happens because my spy doesn't get called.

Any help is much appreciated how to properly spy on FormData methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that I was wrong and the following code actually does spy correctly on the `FormData.append` method:

```
spyOn(FormData.prototype, "append");
```

The issue is that I put it too far nested in my describe blocks that other tests were failing because they also tried to call `FormData.append` and no spy was set up for those tests.

While I was working through a solution, I also realized that the following concept would work too since I don't actually care about uploading any file:

```
spyOn(window, 'FormData').andReturn({
    "append": jasmine.createSpy()
});
```

Hopefully this can help someone that needs to spy on FormData!

Comment: I am getting a  `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function` error. Both window and jasmine seem to be defined though.